# How do I filter a SQL query by exact match to string?

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, filter

I'm using MS SQL 2008 and I have a status field that comes like this:

```
"REF CNF PCNF REL"
```

I need to get all the orders with status `CNF` without returning `PCNF`.
I could do it using spaces before and after `WHERE STATUS LIKE '% CNF %'`, but if CNF is the first or last status it wouldn't work.

One solution that worked was:

```
WHERE 
    PATINDEX('CNF %',STATUS)=0 AND 
    PATINDEX('% CNF %',STATUS)=0 AND
    PATINDEX('% CNF',STATUS)=0
```

But that is just horrible.
Thanks,

Comment: you should normalize the status field into its own table, then this problem basically goes away. You should NEVER store formatted data and/or multiple pieces of data in a single field when you need to deal with "sub-data" of that field on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Marc B., you should normalize your table to avoid storing more than one value in a single field.

If you don't have the credentials to do that, or if you want to keep your model as it is, you can try to add spaces before and after your string:

```
WHERE ' '+STATUS+' ' LIKE '% CNF %'
```

This way you don't have to worry about `CNF` being first or last item in your list.

I don't know if it's the most elegant/effective solution, but it works.

Comment: Wouldn't this involve performing a concatenation on every row in the result set prior to evaluating the `where` clause?  That might get expensive on a large table.

Comment: Sure, but not more than 3 `PATINDEX` calls for example. Looking for patterns in strings (`LIKE`) is already really expensive. For effectiveness, normalization + indexing is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
WHERE STATUS LIKE '% CNF%' OR STATUS LIKE 'CNF%'
```

?

The wildcard `%` matches any character(s), also none.

Comment: What if `CNF` comes in first place ? This ends up being almost as long as OP's solution. And what if there's, say, `CNFF` ?

Comment: First place? Isn't it `...OR STATUS LIKE 'CNF%'`?

Comment: Yes, I agree, but `CNFF` still comes out (I'm assuming this csae could happen in the future, if not right now, as the OP's using spaces as delimiters before and after the value he/she's looking for). Plus, that's not really shorter than OP'solution.

Comment: I thought these four `REF CNF PCNF REL` exist, not `CNFF`. And it's a little shorter...

Comment: Anything might come up, even CNFF (It's not up to me, the client is still deciding the codes for status).

Answer (score 0):

Using [SQL 2008's own internal functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489%28SQL.90%29.aspx), the best I can think of is getting it down to just two conditions like:

```
where STATUS like 'CNF%' or STATUS like '%[^P]CNF%'
```

But if you were willing to [install a .Net add-on](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server-2005-2008), you could use regular expressions like so:

```
where 1 = dbo.RegExpLike(STATUS, '(CNF| CNF)')
```